# Is it possible to update complex data structures in chrome.storage without re-saving everything?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If I want to store persistent data from a chrome extension, I write an object to `chrome.storage`:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value});
```

As far as I know this means I have to store all my extension's data in a single object. This is fine, but what if I want to update only one field in that data structure? Imagine my `chrome.storage.sync` is

```
{
    friends: [
        { name: "Billy", age: 28 }
    ],

    enemies: [
        { name: "Penny", age: 18 },
        { name: "Mortimer", age: 51 }
    ]
}
```

Now suppose I want to go in and just update Mortimer's age. I have to reconstruct the entire above object, modify the appropriate field, and write the whole object back to storage. Is there no way I can just update a single field?

Comment: Of course there's no way as you can see in the API documentation.

Comment: `chrome.storage` transparently serializes data. So the storage actually looks more like `enemies:'[{"name":"Penny","age":18},{"name":"Mortimer","age":51}]'`

Answer (score 1):

the assumption in your question is not correct: "this means I have to store all my extension's data in a single object."

you may use as many objects as you wish. for example, one key for the list of friends, and one key for each friend which maps to the first list by some unique id.

this is much easier with indexedDb or the deprecated web sql, as you could still have some large objects that would need a full re-save, like a list of friends.

Comment: Is it possible to use indexedDB from background.js?

Comment: Nothing, I just wanted to make sure I was going in the right direction before I started coding.

Comment: @JackM, you can use any storage from the background script as you can see in many googlable examples.